# Uploaded rows in Datatables are not affected by hiding columns

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

F.e. I have a table with 20 rows but I set to load only 10 rows, so on start I see 10 rows. I'm using datatables jquery for dealing with tables. When I press load more btn to load 10 more rows they are uploded, added to datatables object and also are appended in table. I can also hide some of the columns. When I hide any column: first 10 rows are affected but the others are not. I have tried to recreate the table, also tried to trigger any column after uploding new rows and these worked. But I want to find out if there is another way to affect uploaded rows.
Here is the table part: [image]

This happens when I hide columns: [image]
These are two ways I have tried and they work without each other [image]
`EnableDataTable` function just recreates the table by doing `$(table).DataTable()` and giving there some options.

Answer (score 0):

Following this part of the Datatables documentation:

https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns().visible()

you can use `table.columns().visible(false)` to hide certain columns,

for your situation you will use

```
table.columns([0 /*,1, 2, 3 */]).visible(false)
```

Incase you don't have the table saved in the initialization, you can retrieve it using

```
var table = $($.fn.DataTable.tables()[0]).DataTable()
```

the `0` is the index of the DataTable, incase there's more than just one table.